# Using co_await vs std async for asynchronous wait

Tags: c++, coroutine

I have seen examples where a thread is created while doing `co_await` in a coroutine, e.g. from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines#co_await

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
 
auto switch_to_new_thread(std::jthread& out) {
  struct awaitable {
    std::jthread* p_out;
    bool await_ready() { return false; }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
      std::jthread& out = *p_out;
      if (out.joinable())
        throw std::runtime_error("Output jthread parameter not empty");
      out = std::jthread([h] { h.resume(); });
      // Potential undefined behavior: accessing potentially destroyed *this
      // std::cout << "New thread ID: " << p_out->get_id() << '\n';
      std::cout << "New thread ID: " << out.get_id() << '\n'; // this is OK
    }
    void await_resume() {}
  };
  return awaitable{&out};
}
 
struct task{
  struct promise_type {
    task get_return_object() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};
 
task resuming_on_new_thread(std::jthread& out) {
  std::cout << "Coroutine started on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
  co_await switch_to_new_thread(out);
  // awaiter destroyed here
  std::cout << "Coroutine resumed on thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
}
 
int main() {
  std::jthread out;
  resuming_on_new_thread(out);
}
```

The application flow from a caller's point of view is very similar to blocking on std async when the function is executed in a different thread. Can someone advice in what situation or use case would calling asynchronous function using `co_await` on a thread be better than using `std::async` with `std:launch::async`?

Comment: From what i am able to understand about coroutine, the main idea of coroutine is to provide low overhead of task switching in comparison to using threads since context switching is not involved when using coroutine. But if a thread is used to resume a coroutine while using co_await, does it not defeat the main purpose of a coroutine ? Not sure what am I missing here.
Also. is a different thread always needed to be involved in order to resume a function after calling co_await?

Comment: Yeah, the whole point of coroutines is to avoid starting & waiting on threads. You've reimplemented `std::async` using coroutines, but the power of continuations comes from composing asynchronous operations not just launching threads of synchronous operations. and std::future isn't going to get you there. checkout out the continuable library (https://naios.github.io/continuable/) for a great implementation of what std::future _should_ have been.